Linkerd config for IPVS loadbalancig mode in AKS Cluster
I have AKS Azure Cluster setup bades on Zaure Linux Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (running on
5.15.0-1054-azure image and containerd://1.7.7-1 container runtime).
I have switched to IPVS mode on this cluster, restarted pods and all is working fine.
Linkerd is also installed on this cluster.
And, now my question is: how to switch Linkerd to work with IPVS? By default it has option:iptablesMode: legacy. - so it works on IpTables still.
I have read that mix of IpTables and IPVS will may cause some delays in serving reqs.
I have checked over internet and some say it is possible but do not show how to do it.
Chat GTP suggests like follows:

Linkerd can be configured to run in IPVS (IP Virtual Server) mode (...) Linkerd supports IPVS mode as an alternative to using the traditional iptables-based proxy mode. Running Linkerd in IPVS mode can offer benefits such as improved performance and scalability, especially in large-scale Kubernetes clusters with a high volume of traffic.To configure Linkerd to use IPVS mode, you need to specify the appropriate configuration settings in Linkerd's control plane configuration. This typically involves setting the proxy mode to ipvs and configuring other parameters related to IPVS behavior.

And Configmap is shown:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: linkerd-config
data:
  proxy: |
    admin:
      ip: 0.0.0.0
      port: 4191
    ipvs:
      enabled: true

I am not sure if it's not gonna destroy my current config.
Versions of Liknerd are:

proxy: cr.l5d.io/linkerd/proxy
proxy-init: cr.l5d.io/linkerd/proxy-init
controller: cr.l5d.io/linkerd/controller


Michal, as discussed, I too cross checked that currently this is not supported officially, I saw a workaround and suggested you the same in my answer. Since that is not helping you, I'm afraid I am not aware of any other workaround to achieve the same..

No problem Arko, as of now linkerd2_proxy I think it's not ready to take IPVS yet. Maybe it will be implemented soon. Posted also question on Linkerd official forum.

Cool. Let me know, if you hear back anything from there. Thanks
